# How to use local dovecot (imap) with Alpine (18.10+ changes)

Tags: email, dovecot, imap

I have been using Alpine mail client with a local dovecot imap server (fed by offlineimap) for many years. Here are my compete 2011 instructions for how to set this up (https://cpbl.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/how-to-alpine-maildir-offlineimap/ ).

I have just updated from 18.04 to 18.10, and my arrangement no longer works. How can I fix it?

Alpine first tells me to replace `localhost` with `localhost/novalidate-cert` in my Alpine config file, and it then if I do that it asks me for a password.  If I grudgingly give it one, it then shows me my /var/spool mailbox instead of my imap mailbox.

The following line is in my .pinerc:

```
rsh-command=/usr/lib/dovecot/imap -c ~/.auto-dovecot.conf 2>> ~/imap.log
```

My .auto-dovecot.conf has nothing but

```
verbose_proctitle = yes

mail_location = maildir:~/imap/mygmail:LAYOUT=fs:INBOX=~/imap/mygmail/INBOX
```

When I run from the command line

```
/usr/lib/dovecot/imap -c ~/.auto-dovecot.conf
```

I see the following (my POSIX username is `meuser`)

> imap(meuser,)Error: net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot/stats-writer)
>   failed: Permission denied
>   * PREAUTH [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT
>   MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS
>   LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES
>   WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY LITERAL+
>   NOTIFY] Logged in as meuser

which tells me that dovecot is running fine. But I do not understand what this is telling me or what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpine hasn't changed from 18.04 to 18.10, but dovecot did.

The problem appears to be an issue that the developers of dovecot are working on.
I have not issued a bug report, but after discussions with lead dev Iko Tuomi, it turns out that the solution is to put the following into `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

```
service stats {
  unix_listener stats-writer {
     mode = 0666
  }
}
```

Then all of my old prescriptions (including the custom `.conf` file that is used for the `imapd` call) work fine as they were. (and I'll update that blog shortly)